# Почему не работают ссылки?

Tags: python, django, url

Делаю комментарии на Django, используя [django-comments-xtd](https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#comments-tags)

Я прописал get_absolute_url(как прописано в документации), чтобы не возникали ошибки, но они возникают, если нажать на кнопку предпросмотра, удаления, ответа на комментарий и т.п. Работает только отправка.
Вот пример ошибки:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /comments/reply/5/
```

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="tit")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("comment")
```

urls:

```
    path('info', Comment2.as_view(), name='comment'),
```

views.py:

```
class Comment2(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/comments.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Comment2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['comment'] = comment
        return context
```

В чем же ошибка?
Правильно ли я прописал get_absolute_url?

Comment: /comments/reply/5 это ссылка? А где шаблон, что в этой ссылке есть изменяемое значение?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу вы используете `primary_key` в ссылке, но при этом в `reverse` она не создается. Метод `get_absolute_url` должен выглядеть как то так

```py
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("comment", kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен pk в ссылке.

Проверил ваш код, вставил pk в ссылку - все то же самое.